# Optional group matching regex

Tags: regex, scala

I’m trying to match optional group in Scala but when I do so it does not provide the value I need.

```
Val regex = “if (.+) then (.+)(?: else (.+))?”
“if x then y else z” match {case regex(c,c1,c2) => println(c,c1,c2)}
```

This prints (x, y else z, null) whereas I expect (x,y,z)

If I remove `?` at end of regex the expression works.

Comment: The `.+` is a very broad match, but like this? `if (.+) then (.+?)(?: else (.+))?` See https://regex101.com/r/Cl4jB2/1